# How to add a class to the body when ever navigate to a particular component or when ever refresh It?

Tags: css, angular

**Problem:**

I have built an angular application. There I want to add a CSS class to the body whenever It navigates to that components and remove it whenever the user leaves out of that component.

This is what I have done. In the global CSS file, I have defined a style like this.

```
.background-color {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#3f51b5, #00bcd4) !important;
  }
```

And In the login component, I have done something like this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";


@Component({
  selector: "app-login",
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./login.component.css"]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    window.onload = function() {
      document.body.classList.add("background-color");
    };
  }
}
```

But this is not working correctly. When I navigate to this component the styles not added but when I refresh the pages it adds the styling to the body. I tried a lot to find a solution to this problem but I was unable to do so. Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No need to write onLoad function inside the **`ngOnInit()`** method. I suggest you read the angular official [**`ngOnit()`**](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit).
rewrite your **`ngOnInit()`** like below

```
    ngOnInit() {
    let element = document.getElementById("bg-color");
    element.classList.add("background-color");
  }
```

and your `component.html` file

```
<p id="bg-color">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uyk4vy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: If you do it this way, you should add the error handeling for case when document is undefined (server side rendering) and also remove the class in OnDestroy

Comment: @Akxe But when I use  Ondestroy in the component, I cannot go to another component using the back button in browser.Could you please tell me a solution to this problem

Comment: @dwp why not? It should omyl occur obce the component is going of screen

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using angular routing, this will not work unless you navigate to that component manually, because when you navigate to a router link, it does not reload the application, it justs removes the other components and add the new component. It does not trigger the onLoad event. But when you reload manually, it will work.

try the following

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
loaded: boolean = false;
constructor() {
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.loaded = true;
}
```

and on the component html

```
<body [class.background-color]="loaded"></body>
```

or something on the similar lines.

Comment: Body is too high in html, it cannot be altered by angular in standard way.

Comment: I understand that and I see the mistake there. But the problem is the `windows.onLoad`